# Zip/Compress a Symbolic Link using Java

Tags: java, unix, zip, symlink

I have a package that depends on symlinks with relative targets.  The package is generated by a Unix system for use by Unix systems.  I'd like to zip this package and preserve the symlinks as they are.

Currently, whenever I zip up the symlink using Jakarta Commons Compress library, java.util.zip.* classes, etc., they follow the link and zip the target file instead.

Do any of you know of a way to zip the files as I'd like?

**Some Background/Notes**

- I do understand that symlinks are Unix-specific whereas Java and
  compression libraries alike try to be as platform-agnostic as
  possible.
- There has been much googling on this topic, but many of the solutions resort to using some form of command-line, which unfortunately, is not an option for me.
- I would like a way to target the reference file that defines the symlink, and compress that.  The only object I can seem to reference is the symlink itself, which ends up translating to the target file.
- The output must be a zip file.

Comment: Just checking for understanding.... Are you wanting a application or a standard zip file as output? Found this on a google search: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_io/0980__Java_nio_Symbolic_Links.htm If this is going to be an application, why not create the symbolic links dynamically when they are needed.

Comment: The output is a zip file.  If it were an application, I have no problems as the java.nio.Files class works perfectly.

Comment: If the output is a zip file.  I'd use unix commands.  

You might have to write the java libraries yourself.  I don't think there is much need for a symbolic link that may not point to anything.  Sorry don't think I can help you.